# Python, packet sniffer with mac. It print weird text

Tags: python-3.x, macos, packet-sniffers

i'm making some packet sniffer with python, that print packet data to console.
it is working but show some weird text like this.

```
1 : E@�4
j#�q���
2 : E@�R4�#�q���
3 : E@��4$#�q���
4 : E@��4�#�q���
5 : E@е4�3#�q���
6 : E@�K4�#�q���
7 : E@Փ4�U#�q���
8 : E@�r4�v#�q���
...
```

if my book is correct, it must be like this

```
1 : b'E\x00\x00(\x18\x19@\x00\x80\x06!\x95\xc0\xa8\x00\x05}\x8d\x82\xe7'
2 : b'E\x00\x00(\x18\x19@\x00\x80\x06!\x95\xc0\xa8\x00\x05}\x8d\x82\xe7'
3 : b'E\x00\x00(\x18\x19@\x00\x80\x06!\x95\xc0\xa8\x00\x05}\x8d\x82\xe7'
4 : b'E\x00\x00(\x18\x19@\x00\x80\x06!\x95\xc0\xa8\x00\x05}\x8d\x82\xe7'
...
```

and whole python code here.

```
from socket import *
import os

def recvData(sock):
    data = ''
    try:
        data = sock.recvfrom(65565)
    except timeout:
        data = ''
    return data[0]

def sniffing(host):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sock_protocol = IPPROTO_IP
    else:
        sock_protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP
    sniffer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, sock_protocol)
    sniffer.bind((host, 1))
    sniffer.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sniffer.ioctl(SIO_RCVALL, RCVALL_ON)

    count = 1
    try:
        while True:
            data = recvData(sniffer)
            print(str(count) + ' : ' + data[:20])
            count += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if os.name == 'nt':
            sniffer.ioctl(SIO_RCVALL, RCVALL_OFF)

def main():
    host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
    print("sniffing : " + host)
    sniffing(host)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i googled few hours but couldn't find same thing.
probably a problem with ascii and unicode, but i'm not sure.

Python : v3.7.1
OSX : Mojave v10.14.1

it will be really helpful if someone find any.

Comment: 'latest' is no version. Ever. Quote the output of `python -V` if you think the version is relevant (and do that, too, even if you think it's irrelevant). Similar goes for OS version.

Comment: are you sure it's python 3? that `str(count) + ' : ' + data[:20]` would not work in python 3 because `data` is bytes. It would work in python 2.

Comment: Oh, im sorry for the poor question. I will check all the things.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, god, please.
I found the problem. I'm definitely using python 3.7.1, `python -V` command return 3.7.1. But when i run this code, automatically ran by python2. I did the alias setting, so i thought it will ran by python3. I manually use python3 with console and it looks fine.
Thank you for the comments, i will check all the features next time.

Comment: Good you provided the answer when you found the problem Jeon.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a Linux OS to run your script. I see that you are using mac, make sure you run this script inside a Virtual Linux environment.